# Is it possible to set expiration for a Redis set?

Tags: redis

On Redis 6.0

```
SADD foo 1
SADD foo 2
SMEMBERS foo     # [1, 2]
EXISTS foo       # 0
EXPIRE foo 10    # 0
```

Setting "EXPIRE" on a set just doesn't work for me, in fact it looks like even "EXISTS" doesn't think the key exists at all.

Is it impossible to set expiration for a Redis set?

Comment: It looks like someone else delete your 'foo' before you run exists and expire

Comment: That looks correct to me. Is the Redis server highly active? Like @for_stack said, maybe it's being deleted. Could be eviction due to Redis filling up if there are lots of other writes.